# Receber resposta de um web service restful java no Android

Tags: android, json, post

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android e gostaria de saber como faço para receber uma resposta do servidor, a tecnologia que estou usando no Android é a retrofit 2.
Após enviar uma requisição POST, como faço para receber uma resposta do servidor e a partir dessa informação fazer um "if" no método onResponse do Android. 
Quando eu executo o aplicativo dá um erro no servidor, nesse caso eu gostaria apenas de receber um true ou false para que a partir dessa resposta poder montar minhas condições no aplicativo.

Segue meu código no Web service:

```
@POST
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Path("Usuario/inserir")
    public boolean inserirUsuario(String content) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        try{
            //JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(content));
            //reader.setLenient(true);
            Usuario u = (Usuario) g.fromJson(content, Usuario.class);
            UsuarioBusiness ub = new UsuarioBusiness();
            System.out.println("Teste saida: " + ub.inserir(u));
            return ub.inserir(u);

        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new NoContentException(content);
        } 
    }
```

Segue o código do método inserir no pacote Business:

```
public boolean inserir(Usuario usuario) {
        UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
        if(dao.inserir(usuario) > 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Segue meu código no Android:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
                            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                dialogo1.setTitle("Sucesso");
                                dialogo1.setMessage("Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!");
                                dialogo1.setNeutralButton("ok", null);
                                dialogo1.show();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                dialogo1.setTitle("Duplicidade");
                                dialogo1.setMessage("Usuario não cadastrado!");
                                dialogo1.setNeutralButton("ok", null);
                                dialogo1.show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
                            txtResult.setText(t.getLocalizedMessage());
                            Log.d("my_tag", "ERROR: " + t.getMessage());
                            Log.d("my_tag", "ERROR: " + t.toString());
                        }
                    });
            }
            });
```

Comment: Até onde eu sei, você não pode (nem deve) criar uma instância de `Callback<T>` ou `Call<T>`. Recomendo que você atualize o retrofit para a versão 2 e leia [esse tutorial sobre retrofit 2](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client). Ele está bem simplificado

Comment: Dessa maneira eu consigo cadastrar um usuário no banco tranquilamente , se eu tentar cadastrar o mesmo usuário recebo uma mensagem no log do servidor dizendo que aquele usuário já existe, meu objetivo seria apenas envia um true ou false para a aplicação android mas não tá dando certo, só joga para o método "onFailure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando receber um tipo `Usuario` quando o servidor está enviando um tipo `boolean`.

Tente alterar seu código para:

```
public interface ClicnetServiceApiContract {  
    @GET("/inserirUsuario")
    Call<boolean> inserirUsuario(@Body Usuario usuario);
}

...

// Aqui você passa o usuário e retorna um objeto to tipo Call<boolean>
Call<boolean> call = seuObjetoApi.inserirUsuario(seuObjetoUsuario);

call.enqueue(new Callback<boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<boolean> call, Response<boolean> response) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<boolean> call, Throwable t) {

        ...
    }
});
```

Isso acontece porque você está tentando fazer uma chamada [assíncrona](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Deu erro ao usar o "boolean", usei o java.lang.Boolean (Boolean) só que acabou gerando esse erro: "Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.Boolean, and Java type boolean, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found".

Comment: @Clicnet, acabei de editar a resposta :)

Comment: No meu método "inserirUsuario" coloquei como retorno uma String e fiz as alterações que você recomendou e agora deu certo. Fico muito agradecido em ter me ajudado. Resolveu um problema que já batia a muitos dias. Muito obrigado!